# Animating box doesnot animate on firefox very well

Tags: css, firefox

Here is the web site=>http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com
The animating box which placed at the bottom of this page is not animating very well. Here are the html codes that has been used on it up to now.

Here is the  code:

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes spincube {
        from,to {
            -webkit-transform:rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
        }
        16% {
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg)
        }
        33% {
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        50% {
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        66% {
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg)
        }
        83% {
            -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg)
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spincube {
        from,to {
            -moz-transform:rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
        }
        16% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg)
        }
        33% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        50% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        66% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg)
        }
        83% {
            -moz-transform:rotateX(90deg)
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes spincube {
        from,to {
            -o-transform:rotateX(0)rotateY(0)rotateZ(0)
        }
        16% {
            -o-transform:rotateY(-90deg)
        }
        33% {
            -o-transform:rotateY(-90deg)rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        50% {
            -o-transform:rotateY(-180deg)rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        66% {
            -o-transform:rotateY(-270deg)rotateX(90deg)
        }
        83% {
            -o-transform:rotateX(90deg)
        }
    }
    @keyframes spincube {
        from,to {
            -moz-transform:rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
            -ms-transform:rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
            transform:rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0)
        }
        16% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotateY(-90deg);
            transform:rotateY(-90deg)
        }
        33% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg);
            transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        50% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
            transform:rotateY(-180deg) rotateZ(90deg)
        }
        66% {
            -moz-transform:rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg);
            transform:rotateY(-270deg) rotateX(90deg)
        }
        83% {
            -moz-transform:rotateX(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotateX(90deg);
            transform:rotateX(90deg)
        }
    }
    .cubespinner {
        -webkit-animation-name:spincube;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -webkit-animation-duration:12s;
        -moz-animation-name:spincube;
        -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        -moz-animation-duration:12s;
        animation-name:spincube;
        animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-duration:12s;
        -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform-origin:60px 60px 0;
        -moz-transform-origin:60px 60px 0;
        -ms-transform-origin:60px 60px 0;
        transform-origin:60px 60px 0
    }
    .cubespinner div {
        position:absolute;
        width:120px;
        height:120px;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        text-align:center;
        font-size:100px
    }
    .cubespinner .face1 {
        -webkit-transform:translateZ(60px);
        -moz-transform:translateZ(60px);
        -ms-transform:translateZ(60px);
        -o-transform:translateZ(60px);
        transform:translateZ(60px)
    }
    .cubespinner .face2 {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -moz-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -ms-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -o-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px)
    }
    .cubespinner .face3 {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -moz-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -ms-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -o-transform:rotateY(90deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px)
    }
    .cubespinner .face4 {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        transform:rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -o-transform:rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px)
    }
    .cubespinner .face5 {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -ms-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -o-transform:rotateY(-90deg) rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(60px)
    }
    .cubespinner .face6 {
        -webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -moz-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -ms-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
        transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
        -o-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px)
    }
    div.stage img {
        vertical-align:inherit
    }
```

```html
<div class="stage wow zoomInLeft animated" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" style="width: 120px; height: 120px; margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 10%; visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1000ms; animation-delay: 300ms; animation-name: zoomInLeft;">
  <div class="cubespinner">
    <div class="face1"><img src="http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com/images/picx.jpg" style="opacity:0.7;" height="120" width="90"></div>
    <div class="face2"><img src="http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com/images/picx.jpg" style="opacity:0.7;" height="120" width="90"></div>
    <div class="face3"><img src="http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com/images/picx.jpg" style="opacity:0.7;" height="120" width="90"></div>
    <div class="face4"><img src="http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com/images/picx.jpg" style="opacity:0.7;" height="120" width="90"></div>
    <div class="face5"><img src="http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com/images/picx.jpg" style="opacity:0.7;" height="120" width="90"></div>
    <div class="face6"><img src="http://waruna0sanjaya-001-site1.btempurl.com/images/picx.jpg" style="opacity:0.7;" height="120" width="90"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the code. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are welcome. You can make an snippet or a https://jsfiddle.net to share the code with a working example

Comment: For me, the cube in the bottom of the page works well. I'm using firefox v42

Comment: There is a small shaking occurs on the front face from time to time.

Comment: I update your post with the css and html related. Have you seen anything worse? I don't see it.

Comment: Yes. Then it may be a fault with my vga or something. I do not know.

Comment: I can't tell you nothing more because the code seems ok and I see the animation allright. You can hold on in this topic waiting for someone that can help you. Sorry a lot because I can't help you :(